# Web Scraping through multiple urls

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I have the code I would like for the content I need, however i would like to run through all the gameId's that have played so far instead of just the one in the URL. I would like to change 2017020001 and make it go through to 2017021272 or till the end of the season which is around 1272 i believe. How can that be done with the code below?

```
import csv
import requests
import os

req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2017020001/feed/live?site=en_nhl')
data = req.json()

my_data = []
pk = data['gameData']['game']['pk']
for item in data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']:
    players = item.get('players')
    if players:
        player_a = players[0]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 0 else None
        player_b = players[1]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 1 else None
    else:
        player_a, player_b = None, None
    event = item['result']['event']
    time = item['about']['periodTime']
    triCode = item.get('team', {}).get('triCode')
    coordinates_x, coordinates_y = item['coordinates'].get('x'), item['coordinates'].get('y')
    my_data.append([pk, player_a, player_b, event, time, triCode, coordinates_x, coordinates_y])

headers = ["pk", "player_a", "player_b", "event", "time", "triCode", "coordinates_x", "coordinates_y"]

with open("NHL_2017020001.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the game ids are numbered sequentially then it would be as simple as nesting all your code under a for loop that iterates through all the game ids and using str.format() add the necessary padding to the number in this case some parts would change:

```
import csv
import requests
import os

for i in range(1, 1273):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/201702{:04d}/feed/live?site=en_nhl'.format(i)
    req = requests.get(url)
    req.raise_for_status()
    data = req.json()
    my_data = []
    pk = data['gameData']['game']['pk']
    for item in data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']:
        players = item.get('players')
        if players:
            player_a = players[0]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 0 else None
            player_b = players[1]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 1 else None
        else:
            player_a, player_b = None, None
            event = item['result']['event']
            time = item['about']['periodTime']
            triCode = item.get('team', {}).get('triCode')
        coordinates_x, coordinates_y = item['coordinates'].get('x'), item['coordinates'].get('y')
        my_data.append([pk, player_a, player_b, event, time, triCode, coordinates_x, coordinates_y])

        headers = ["pk", "player_a", "player_b", "event", "time", "triCode", "coordinates_x", "coordinates_y"]

    with open("NHL_201702{:04d}.csv".format(i), "a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(my_data)
```

One last correction is that using `with ... as` makes it so that you don't need to close the file explictily.
You can find additional information on using str.format() [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: The [`stop` in `range` should be `1272+1`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) since it won't include the stop value in the resulting sequence.

Comment: Thats not working with the code above. Have you tested it with it by chance?

Comment: Its when says name data is not defined. when i change it it says response object is not subscriptable. alittle stuck

Comment: Have you tried checking if the request is succesful before trying to acces the data? This is done by ensuring the following evaluates to true after running the request.get() function :  `req.status_code == 200`

Comment: Not sure how to do that, new to this.

Comment: I can access the data in my previous code no problem, it’s the integration of the range that is the issue

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but I've copied the code and tested it and it seems to work fine. I'm editing the original answer to show the full program as I have run it with the part to check for a status error added in the line `req.raise_for_status()`

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over your code using a for-loop

Something like this should work:

```
import csv
import requests
import os

for x in range(2017020001, 2017021273):
    req = requests.get('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/%s/feed/live?site=en_nhl' % x)
    data = req.json()

    my_data = []
    pk = data['gameData']['game']['pk']
    for item in data['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']:
        players = item.get('players')
        if players:
            player_a = players[0]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 0 else None
            player_b = players[1]['player']['fullName'] if len(players) > 1 else None
        else:
            player_a, player_b = None, None
        event = item['result']['event']
        time = item['about']['periodTime']
        triCode = item.get('team', {}).get('triCode')
        coordinates_x, coordinates_y = item['coordinates'].get('x'), item['coordinates'].get('y')
        my_data.append([pk, player_a, player_b, event, time, triCode, coordinates_x, coordinates_y])

    headers = ["pk", "player_a", "player_b", "event", "time", "triCode", "coordinates_x", "coordinates_y"]

    with open("NHL_2017020001.csv", "a", newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(my_data)
    f.close()
```

Comment: The `stop` value of `2017021272` in [`range` should be `2017021272+1`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) since it won't include the stop value in the resulting sequence.